# How to get a JSON value in javascript code in the same package?

Tags: json

I have to files in my package:
**file1.json**

```
{
  "web" : "https://gmail.com",
  "login" : "login@gmail.com",
  "password" : "password",
}
```

**file2.js**

I want to retrieve data from .json file in my code (for example, password), while these two files are in one package. How can I import **password** value? May I use jquery for this?

***Thank you in advance***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how do you mean a package? If that's Node.JS, you can use `require` or import:

```
// 0 standard require 
const { password } = require('./file')
// 1 the most concise way
import { password } from './file'
// 2 works with json also
import { password } from './file.json'
// 3 might also need to import default object 
import file from './file'
const password = file.password
```

Answer (score 1):

*May I use jquery for this?* **YES** You can go for <kbd>[$.getJSON](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)</kbd> method

```
$.getJSON( "file1.json", function( data ) {

   //data is the content of your file

});
```

Comment: sorry, can't understand